# Does passing in params in my order clause leave me option to sql injection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I do this:

```
User.where(....).order("#{params[:order]} #{params[:dir]}")
```

If no, then for arguements sake say I want to be paranoid and ensure the values for the symbols :order and :dir are within a range, how could I do that?

Say I create an array of allowable safe values:

```
safe_order = %[:updated_at :created_at]
```

what would be the ruby way of ensuring `params[:order]` is either `nil` or contains 1 of the values in the safe_order array?

Comment: no the way you are handling it prevents you from that. Basically AR prevents you from all SQL injection.

Comment: It prevents it when you use placeholders, but I'm not so sure when you plop it into a string like that.

Comment: AR does not prevent all SQL injection. The code above may be open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns

Specifically some small methods to check the parameters or return defaults:

```
 def index
   @products = Product.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
 end

 # ...

 private

 def sort_column
   Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
 end

 def sort_direction
   %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
 end
```